# how to eliminate conflicts in Operator Precedence Grammar?

Tags: parsing, operator-precedence, context-free-grammar

Given the following grammar (non-terminals are capitalized),

```
S -> aSbXc
   | abXc
X -> aa
```

we can build the precedence matrix for it, as follows.

```
     a   b   c   #
  ーーーーーーーーーー
a | <,=  =   >  
b |  <       =
c |      >       >
# |  <           =
```

where, symbol '#' marks the start and end of a string.

- < means yield precedence
- > means take precedence
- = means equal precedence

According to the matrix, the above grammar is not an Operator Precedence Grammar, since a<a and a=a.

Is it possible to eliminate such conflict, e.g., by rewriting the grammar?

Comment: Doesn't `X->aA A->a` work?

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is there a general way of rewriting the grammar?

Comment: Not that I.know of. I don't think there is even an algorithm which can tell you whether a language has an operaror precedence grammar
.